# How to disable the zoom of a plotly chart in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I didn't find an argument to disable the zoom mode of the mouse cursor on a plotly graph. This is bad because when you drag your fingers across your phone, the zoom increases. Taking advantage of the question, I would like to remove all the buttons from the plotly and leave only the button to download the image.

Comment: See: https://plotly-r.com/control-modebar.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a lot you can do! The button line in `plotly` is called "modebar" and you can remove it completely, or remove specific buttons from it:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c("zoomIn2d", "zoomOut2d"))
```

See more details in the book [Interactive web-based data visualization with R, plotly, and shiny](https://plotly-r.com/control-modebar.html).

([Documentation](https://plotly.com/r/configuration-options/#online-configuration-options) is unfortunately very brief.)

If you want not only to disable buttons, but also to disable zooming completely, use `layout()` with `xaxis` and `yaxis` arguments to fix the axis range by `fixedrange` settings (note it has to be a list):

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(x = 1:10,y = 1:10) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE), yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE))
```

See [xaxis](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-fixedrange) and [yaxis](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-fixedrange) documentation for zooming.

Comment: Petr, this only omits the buttons, but the zoom mode on the cursor continues ...

Comment: @IgorCobelo Hi Igor, oh, sorry, my mistake. I have updated the answer with a solution to disable zooming, see [xaxis](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-fixedrange) and [yaxis](https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-fixedrange)... hope it helps this time :-)

Comment: It also works with `ggplotly(p) |> layout(xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE), yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE))` :)