# ignore traces for autoscale button in plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

```python
import numpy as np                                                                                                
import plotly.graph_objects as go                                                                                 
                                                                                                                  
fig = go.Figure()                                                                                                 
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=np.random.random(10), y=np.random.random(10), mode="markers"), name="1st trace")                        
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[-0.23, 12], y=[0.17, -17], mode="markers", name="2nd trace"))                                          
fig.show()
```

Is there a way to ignore the second trace and only consider the first trace for the Autoscale button?